# Select only a subset of an Entities Collection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

If I have a Entity which contains a `@OneToMany`, using JPA How do I select the entity and only a subset of the related children? I cannot use the `@Where` or `@Filter` annotations.

**More Details**
I am translating our Business model into something more general so don't worry about the example not making sense IRL. But the Query has lots (more than this example) of `left join fetch` cases. Friend has no relations and just a string name.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int parentId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "friendId")
    private Friend friends;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Child> childrenSet = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
public class Child {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private int childId;

     private boolean blonde;

     @ManyToOne(fetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Parent parent;
}
```

```
@Query( "SELECT p " +
        "FROM Parent p " +
        "JOIN FETCH p.friends f " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.childrenSet c " + 
        "WHERE f.name IS NOT NULL " +
        "AND c.blonde = true")
List<Parent> getParentsWithListOfOnlyBlondeChildren();
```

**Test Class**

```
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class TestParentRepo {
    @PersistenceContxt
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private ParentRepo parentRepo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Child c1 = new Child();
        c1.setBlonde(true);
        Child c2 = new Child();
        c2.setBlonde(false);

        Friend friend1 = new Friend();
        friend1.setName("friend1");

        Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
        children.add(c1);
        children.add(c2);

        Parent parent1 = new Parent();
        parent1.setFriends(friend1);

        c1.setParent(parent1);
        c2.setParent(parent1);

        entityManager.persist(friend1);
        entityManager.persist(parent1);
        entityManager.persist(c1);
        entityManager.persist(c2);

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest() {
        List<Parent> parent = parentRepo.getParentsWithListOfOnlyBlondeChildren();

        System.out.println(parent);
    }
}
```

Now when debugging what I **GET** is the Parent Object with BOTH children in the set. What I **WANT** is The parent with only c1 (blonde = true).

What does the query have to be to filter out the related Child entities that don't match the criteria?

I am trying to avoid doing: Query Parents, for each parent Query Children matching criteria.

**Edit**
After more testing I have found that this only does not work when running tests, ie, the problem is with getting the expected result using H2 DB in unit tests. The query works fine when running with an actual MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `@Query`(atleast for simple queries like this one), If you are using `spring-data-jpa`, you can just write a method like this in your repository class

```
List<Parent> findByChildrenSet_Blonde(boolean isBlonde)
```

spring-data will formulate and execute the query for you by looking at the Method name. `_` is to denote dependent class field

Now you can call this function like this

```
findByChildrenSet_Blonde(true)
```

You could also write

```
List<Parent> findByChildrenSet_BlondeTrue()
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It returned a List of 2 Parent objects (the same object) both with both children, blonde and !blonde.

Comment: Then there is something wrong in the data. Check your data. Also check the documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods. I guess u r missing a line in your test. Try this `parent1.setChildrenSet(children)`

Comment: You are right, there is something missing but it's not in the data, it's in the question. It's only happening when running the test on the H2 DB. When I run it fully with an actual MySQL database it works as expected.

Comment: Tthat shud not be the case. Did the above query work for you in with MySql?

Comment: Yes, it did. When I set up a test endpoint to call the repository method you suggested with the full MySQL instance plugged in it all worked exactly as expected/wanted. So I'm lead to believe it's H2 (or at least my configuration of it) that doesn't work the way we want it to.